# Can a magnet pick up heated iron filings?

Tags: electromagnetism

I heard that heat can destroy magnetism (somehow randomize the electrons orientation and reduce the magnetism), but I like to know if magnetism could affect heated iron filings? (Here heated means raising the iron filings temperature until the magnet can no longer attract it.)

Answer (score 2):

[Ferromagnetism dissapears above the curie temperature.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Curie_temperature) High temperatures disrupt the magnetic field of ferromagnetic permanent magnets, as well as the ability of ferromagnetic materials to be attracted to magnets. In iron this temperature is 1043K. Above this temperature there is still paramagnetism, but it is weak compared to ferromagnetism.